# Http client cannot be resolved in selenium

Tags: eclipse, selenium, classpath, apache-commons-httpclient, eclipse-classpath

I have imported `httpclient` jar files, but this command cannot be resolved in eclipse or in selenium. But when click in error, it shows option to import but it doesn't work.

```
final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams(); 
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000); 
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 30000); 
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url); 
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(input, HTTP.UTF_8)); 
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post); 
client.getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();
```

Comment: Hi @sreekutty, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please provide a formatted code sample to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(input, HTTP.UTF_8));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
client.getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();